# Sails js model create is not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

When I am trying to create a new CompanyProduct . I am getting this error

**CompanyProduct Model:**

```
/**
* CompanyProduct.js
 *
 * @description :: This is a clients product inventory
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */

module.exports = {
    tableName: 'company_products',
    sortValues: ['companies', 'products'],

attributes: {
    'quantity': {
        'type': 'integer',
        size: 6
    },
    'cost_per_unit': {
        'type': 'integer'
    },

    // Associations
    'product': {
        'columnName': 'product_id',
        'model': 'product',
        'required': true
    },
    'company': {
        'columnName': 'company_id',
        'model': 'company',
        'required': true
    }
},

getSortValues: function() {
    return this.sortValues;
}
};
```

Comment: {
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",  
  "status": 400,  
  "summary": "2 attributes are invalid",  
  "model": "CompanyProduct",  
  "invalidAttributes": {  
    "quantity": [  
      {
        "rule": "integer",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a integer (instead of \"10\", which is a number)"
      }
    ],
    "cost_per_unit": [
      {
        "rule": "integer",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a integer (instead of \"100\", which is a number)"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: From where are you trying to create the model? `CompanyProduct.create()` or a http request or what? We'll need to see the code with which you're trying to create the model entity!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to set `quantity` to `"10"` and `cost_per_unit` to `"100"` instead of `10` and `100`.

Probably, sails doesn't parse those values as integers.

Try to assign to CompanyProduct this kind of object:

```
{
    "quantity": 10,
    "cost_per_unit": 100
}
```

Comment: CompanyProduct.create({
      quantity :10,
      cost_per_unit:100,
      product:1,
      company:1
    }).then((companyProduct)=>{
       if(!companyProduct) return res.negotiate(err);
      return res.ok(companyProduct);
    }).catch(err=>{
      return res.negotiate(err);
    })

Comment: What type do those field have in your models?

Comment: `'quantity': {`
        `'type': 'integer',`
    `size: 6`
   },
  `cost_per_unit:` {`
       `type: 'integer'`
    `}`

Comment: Are you using MySQL as a DB?